# How to check if a number is rational or irrational in R?

Tags: r

How do i create a function that returns sqrt(2) as irrational as an output in R?
& returns sqrt(10740), sqrt(1111+2/3) as rational as an output?

Comment: [This answer on Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/) might be helpful.

Comment: Because decimals aren't represented with infinite precision, you can always put them over 10 to the power of one more than the precision. You could check that there's a suitably small denominator, I guess, but `MASS::as.fractions(sqrt(2))` returns `8119/5741`, which isn't that extreme, so that's not much better.

Comment: @alistaire Both `pi - fractions(pi)` and `sqrt(2) - fractions(sqrt(2))` return `0`. The help `?as.fractions` page says *"Arithmetic operations on "fractions" objects have full floating point accuracy, but the character representation printed out may not."*.

Comment: Are you only concerned with values from `sqrt`? If so, you may be able to exploit the rational root theorem.